# Getting error in flow when using uiObjectAPI on LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I have created a LWC component, and exposed the same in a flow as a screen.

I have noticed that when I add the following line to the js file, the flow errors out
import {getObjectInfo} from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoAPI';

Error Received:
Action.prototype.finishAction Error [Assertion Failed!: Failed to find definition for dependency: lightning/uiObjectInfoAPI : undefined Callback failed: serviceComponent://ui.interaction.runtime.components.controllers.FlowRuntimeController/ACTION$runInterview]

if I comment out the import statement, the flow works fine. Is there anything else that I need to do to make the uiObjectInfoAPI work in Flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identified the issue. It was a Case sensitive issue. I was using lightning/uiObjectInfoAPI instead of lightning/uiObjectInfoApi